# How do i display different results in SQL if a column is null or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column (of type `Date`) that is either null or not null. I want to create a column that displays either "Completed" or "Not Completed" based on the column being null or not. I've looked around and could find `IsNull()` but that only allowed me to select one result.

I imagine a SQL statement like below but are unable to find the required syntax.

```
select rowID, if(isNull(CompletedDate), "Yes", "No")
From Table
```

**Sample data**

```
| RowID | CompletedDate |
|   1   | 2015-12-01    |
|   2   |               |
|   3   | 2015-12-01    |
```

**Intended result**

```
| RowID | Completed|
|   1   | Yes      |
|   2   | No       |
|   3   | Yes      |
```

This is done using SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this:

```
select
  rowid,
  case when completeddate is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as Completed
from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `CASE`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms181765(v=sql.120).aspx

```
select rowID, CASE WHEN CompletedDate IS NULL THEN 'No'
                   ELSE 'Yes'
              END as Completed
From Table
```

Answer (score 1):

In `SELECT` statement:

```
IF C THEN R                         = CASE WHEN C THEN R END
IF C THEN R1 ELSE R2                = CASE WHEN C THEN R1 ELSE R2 END
IF C1 THEN R1 ELSE IF C2 THEN R2... = CASE WHEN C1 THEN R1 WHEN C2 THEN R2... END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select rowID, if(isNull(CompletedDate), "Yes", "No")
From Table
```

Its a MySql syntax `if(isNull(CompletedDate), "Yes", "No")` but in SQL Server you can achieve by using `CASE` or `IIF` condition.

With CASE:

```
select 
    rowID, 
    CASE WHEN CompletedDate IS NULL THEN 'No'
         ELSE 'Yes'
    END as Completed
```

With `IIF` condition:

```
select 
    rowID, 
    IIF(CompletedDate IS NULL, 'No', 'Yes') as Completed
```

Comment: **Note:** `IIF` is only available in SQL Server **2012** and newer

Comment: You are right, I am believing mostly people are using SQL SERVER 2012 in end of 2015 :)

Comment: You'd be **surprised** how many folks still use SQL Server 2008, 2005, and some even **2000** !! Even at the end of 2015 ....

Comment: Yep, still stuck on SQL Server 2008. Once you've got apps etc on it upgrading can become an expensive risky activity that nobody wants to pay for.